ARM template with list of resources in different resource groups
I have to update some existing ARM templates to deploy a pair of resources (NSG, VNet) to multiple resource groups, where the resource groups are passed to the template as an array.
Q: How do I make the VNet depend on the NSG that's in the same resource group?
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

  "parameters": {
    "listOfRGs": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": ["rg1", "rg2",..."rgN"],
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "rgNsgCopyIdx",
        "count": "[length(parameters('listOfRGs'))]",
        "input": {
           "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
           "name": "myNSG",
           "resourceGroup": "[parameters('listOfRGs')[copyIndex('rgNsgCopyIdx')]]",
           .... and some other properties
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "rgVNetCopyIdx",
        "count": "[length(parameters('listOfRGs'))]",
        "input": {
           "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
           "name": "myVNET",
           "resourceGroup": "[parameters('listOfRGs')[copyIndex('rgVNetCopyIdx')]]",
           "dependsOn": [
             "<WHAT GOES HERE TO DEPEND ON THE NSG IN THE SAME RESOURCE GROUP>"
           ]
        }
      },
    ]
  ]
}


I think you need to use Microsoft.Resources/deployments and copy. let's say you have three resource groups.

rgCenter
rg1
rg2

rgCenter is used to run the deployment, and which will invoke the two deployments in rg1 and rg2
deploy.ps1
$rgName = "rgCenter"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "testDeployment" -ResourceGroupName $rgName -TemplateFile "template.json"

template.json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        "listOfRGs": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": ["rg1", "rg2"]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "copy": {
                "name": "rgcopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('listOfRGs'))]"
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[format('{0}deployment', parameters('listOfRGs')[copyIndex()])]",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('listOfRGs')[copyIndex()]]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
                            "apiVersion": "2023-02-01",
                            "name": "nsg1",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
                            "name": "vnet1",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [
                                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "subnets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "subnet1",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                                 "id": "[resourceId(parameters('listOfRGs')[copyIndex()] ,'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', 'nsg1')]"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}

deployment history in rgCenter

resource deployed in rg1

resource deployed in rg2

